# redirecting to a URL query string

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect a page to:

product_page.php?rest_id=$rest_id&area=$rest_city

for example:

product_page.php?rest_id=3&area=Enfield

At the moment the page is redirecting to:

http://localhost/PhpProject2/product_page.php?rest_id=&area=

Even though i have specified :

```
  if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])){
  $rest_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['rest_id']); 
  }
  if (isset($_GET['area'])){
  $area = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['area']); 
  }
  if (isset($_GET['add_item'])) {
  (int)$_GET['add_item']]){
   $_SESSION['Shopping_cart_' . (int) $_GET['add_item']]+='1';

  //redirect
  echo"<script>window.open('product_page.php?rest_id=$rest_id&area=$rest_city','_self')</script>"; //header does not work
 }
```

How would i go about getting the echo to re-direct to the correct page.

**What i have tried:**

- Calling both add_item, rest_id and rest_city in the same if asset.
- Moving the $_GET rest_id and rest_city closing tag after the echo.

The two above options just stop the page from re-directing all together, this is my first time doing this, any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntax errors in your code. Also, the way you echo the string is wrong. You need to concat the variables with the string, using the PHP concatenation operator, else use double quotes.

---

Below fixed your errors:

```
if (isset($_GET['rest_id'])){
    $rest_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['rest_id']); 
}

if (isset($_GET['area'])){
    $area = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_GET['area']); 
}

if (isset($_GET['add_item'])) {

$_SESSION['Shopping_cart_'] = (int) $_GET['add_item']+='1';

    echo"<script>window.open('product_page.php?rest_id=" . $rest_id . "&area=" . $rest_city . "','_self')</script>";
}
```

Comment: I am creating a shopping cart. so if a item is added add 1 to the session

Comment: my login form? i do not have one

Comment: @Monroe I mean your form. Where does `$_GET['rest_id']` gets assigned

Comment: oh sorry, misunderstanding. it is a restaurant_id within my DB. Every restaurant on creation is given a rest_id.

Comment: @Monroe I think that the problem lies with the assign of the variable. As it echoed blank, it means values are not assigned, maybe query failed?

Comment: That the thing, everything works perfectly. Even on the product page, the restId and city name are in the url, thats why i do not understand why i cannot get them. even if i echo out all the if asset... $_GET[...] the right rest_id number and city_name print

Comment: @Monroe Can you post the code where you assign the variables?

Comment: on the products page or the page above

Answer (score 0):

You should use double qotes [**"string *$variable* string"**] for variable to work inside a string or if not you should concatenate the string with [**.**] sign.

```
echo"<script>window.open('product_page.php?rest_id=$rest_id&area=$rest_city','_self')</script>";
```

This will not work because of single qoute [']

Regards